# How to pass argument with no information for ggplot

Tags: r, function, plot, ggplot2

I am creating a function that plots a plot using `ggplot2`. I intend to use a loop to plot different data.frames. Most of the time I will be passing a vector of lines (using the argument `lines`) to be used with `geom_vline`:

```
+ geom_vline(xintercept = lines)
```

This works great assuming the particular plot should have lines. But one of the plots has no lines. Is there any vector I can pass in `lines` that will not produce any lines?

Comment: does `NULL` work for you?

Comment: Nope, unfortunately `NULL` creates a line at `x=0`.

Comment: Why not just conditionally add that layer? If there are no lines, don't add that layer.

Comment: Can you show an example please: `p <- qplot(-10:10, -10:10, geom="line") ; p + geom_vline(xintercept = 5) ; p + geom_vline(xintercept = NULL)` seems not to add a line at x=0. But yup, MrFlick's idea of rethinking the flow seems sensible

Comment: MrFlick's idea should work.

Comment: In @user20650's example, NA works as well.